# Visual Studio 2013 crashes when opening a Unity 3D project?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to load an existing Unity 3D project into Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.  Every time I do it crashes.  Before VS2013 automatically restarted, I managed to see an "Unsupported Project" warning with a reference to this project element:

*Assembly-UnityScript-firstpass.unityproj: The application which this project type is based on was not found. Please try this link for further information: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=299083&projecttype=C58B1F1F-8686-7922-EDE1-281471AD9A9E*

Thinking it was an Extension issue I downloaded and installed the *Visual Studio 2013 Tools for Unity 3D* extension.  That did not help.  Has anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: Do you use Resharper?

Comment: @Formic No, I don't.

Comment: Try deleting all of the Visual studio files from the root unity folder, then in unity under the Visual Studio Tools menu (If you haven't imported the package after installing the VS tools, do that from Assets > Import Package > Visual Studio Tools 2013) click 'Generate Project Files'

Comment: If that works for you let me know and I can place it as an answer so that others with the same problem can find the solution.